# Relation between sequences in sequence spaces $l^p$ and $l^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Fix a $p \in [1,\infty]$. Let $\{{a_n}\}_{n=1}^∞$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that $\{{a_nx_n}\}_{n=1}^∞ \in l^p$ for all sequences ${\{x_n}\}_{n=1}^∞ \in l^p$. Show that ${\{a_n}\}_{n=1}^∞ \in l^∞$.

My try:
For p=$∞$, for $\{{a_nx_n}\}_{n=1}^∞ \in l^∞$ for all sequences ${\{x_n}\}_{n=1}^∞ \in l^∞$.In particular letting ${\{x_n}\}=1$ gives that ${\{a_n}\}\in l^∞$. I couldn't solve it for p=[1,∞).
Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose $(a_n) \notin \ell^{\infty}$. Then we can find integers  $n_1<n_2<..  $ such that $|a_{n_k}| >2^{k}$. Let $x_n=0$ if $n \notin \{n_1,n_2,...\}$ and let $x_{n_k}=\frac 1  {a_{n_k}}$. Check that $(x_n) \in \ell^{p}$ but $(a_nx_n) \notin \ell^{p}$.